# Why does tkinter not add the label text to the window?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

i am trying to set up a very minimal tkinter example, the window gets created and displayed, but it is empty, the text doesn't get added.

my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("230x200")
greeting = tk.Label(text="Hello, Tkinter")
greeting.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

i have also tried `place` instead of `pack`, as well as using `tk.Label(window, text="Hello, Tkinter")`, also tried both with and without setting the geometry, that just changes how big the window appears, but it stays empty either way.

i also tried both within my ide (pycharm) and outside of the ide, same result with both, the window gets created and displayed but stays empty.

edit: using python 3.9.6 in the pycharm venv, python 3.11.5 for the test outside the ide

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue in my Windows 11 with Python 3.11.5.  Try changing the text color.

Comment: @acw1668 tried changing the color to red `tk.Label(text="Hello, Tkinter", foreground="red")`, still just an empty window.

Comment: If your platform is MacOS, try reinstall Python from python.org.

Comment: @acw1668 ok, that reinstall helped, thanks, i thought i did the install with brew for tkinter correctly as the error of it not being configured for tkinter went away after running `brew install python-tk`, but it only helped partially from the looks of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling python from [python.org](https://www.python.org/) instead of using homebrew's python install solved the problem